# Android. Fit webview size to youtube video size

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I'd like to play youtube video by using android webview. **But I want to fit my webview to youtube video size.** Until now, my implementaion is like below.

```
        String vid = TextUtils.extractYoutubeVId(body);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(vid)) {
            return null;
        }

        String html = "<html > <head></head> <body style=\"margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;\"> <iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/___\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe> </body> </html> ";
        html = html.replace("___", vid);

        mImportedVideoWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = mImportedVideoWebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mImportedVideoWebview.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

mImportedVideoWebview is just a WebView and its width is MATCH_PARENT and height is 350dp.

By using above code, I can play youtube video.

But, I want to put my webview width to screen width and fit my webview's height to youtube video height proportionally. Anyone help me plz!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use below code snipe hope it will

```
<html><body><iframe frameborder=0 allowfullscreen width=100% height=100% src=link  frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```